# Why does using traits with type member give "error: type mismatch" in subtrait?

Tags: scala, traits

I want to define some traits that describe different tree nodes as follows:

```scala
trait Node 

trait HasParent {
    this: Node =>
    type P <: Node with HasChildren

    def parent: P
    def setParent(parent: P)
}

trait HasChildren {
    this: Node =>

    def children: Seq[Node]

    protected def add[T <: Node with HasParent](child: T) {
        child.setParent(this) //        error: type mismatch;
//      found   : HasChildren with Node
//      required: child.P
//              child.setParent(this)
    }
}
```

Can you please explain, why this code doesn't compile? What is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type `P` defined in `HasParent` is an abstract type. That means each `HasParent` may have another type `P` as long as it satisfies the (upper) type bound.

When you call `setParent` on *some* `HasParent` with a `T`, you have no guarantee that `this` has the required type of that particular `HasParent`.

Are you sure you did not want to write:

```
type P = Node with HasChildren
```

Comment: Thanks. It compiles now. Intllij IDEA still highlights this code as error :) But how I can override P with some other trait, something like HasSomeSpecialChildren?

Comment: You cannot override concrete type members. In any case, if you change `P`, you have to make sure that the `this` reference in `HasChildren` has the correct type when you call `add`... It is probably better to use subtypes for that and a type parameter on the `HasParent`.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by subtypes? Sorry, I'm new in Scala. Could you give the right example for my situation?

Comment: It is unclear to me what exactly you want to represent with varying `P` and why you need it. Can you elaborate please?